# Падение RxJava на Android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, rxjava

После установки `API level` на `17` (был `21`), стало падать приложение.

---

Метод, где падает приложение:

```
private Observable<Notification> createHandleObservable() {
    return Observable.create(DocumentHandleObservableOnSubscribe.getInstance())
                .repeatWhen(observable -> observable.delay(HANDLE_INTERVAL_MIN, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

Ошибка:

```
11-01 20:08:10.025 31944-31944/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rostislav.dugin.reminderofwork, PID: 31944
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.plugins.RxJavaPlugins
          at rx.Observable.<clinit>(Observable.java:62)
          at com.rostislav.dugin.reminderofwork.DocumentHandleService.createHandleObservable(DocumentHandleService.java:58)
          at com.rostislav.dugin.reminderofwork.DocumentHandleService.onStartCommand(DocumentHandleService.java:32)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2868)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rostislav.dugin.reminderofwork"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

`pro-rules.pro`:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontoptimize
```

---

Из-за чего ошибка и как ее исправить?

---

**UPD_0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rostislav.dugin.reminderofwork">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".SettingActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".DocumentHandleService" />
        <receiver android:name=".NotificationShower" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Покажите манифест.

Comment: @post_zeew, обновил.

Comment: Посмотрите [сюда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37632531), может быть поможет.

Comment: @post_zeew, я смотрел, только не въехал в ответ. А вот ваш — помог.

Comment: Помогло добавление `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`?

Comment: @post_zeew, да.

Comment: @post_zeew, блин! Еще и библиотека для парсинга `.xlsx` закрашилась...

Comment: Это лучше в новый вопрос вынесите.

Comment: @post_zeew, ну это само собой...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `AndroidManifest.xml` к тегу `application` добавьте атрибут:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```